# postgresql take timezone changes until restart service

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I'm getting a little confused by postgresql timezones
i was checking the dates in some rows and i noticed the timezone -4 in them
but my actual timezone is -3
the government made changes to the daylight saving timezones and the tzdata files where changes
the system date was fine but postgres don't notice the change until i restarted it

i tried setting it with
     set TIME ZONE LOCAL 
but it sill got the bad timezone -4

```
select extract(epoch from now()),now();
date_part     |             now              
------------------+------------------------------
 1335240339.68894 | 2012-04-24 00:05:39.68894-04
(1 fila)
```

but after i restarted postgresql

```
# select extract(epoch from now()),now();
```

date_part    |              now
     ----------------+-------------------------------

```
  1335240403.672 | 2012-04-24 01:06:43.672002-03
 (1 fila)
```

my timezone was always

```
 show timezone;
     TimeZone     
------------------
 America/Santiago
(1 fila)
```

may i need to restart postgres every time tzdata info is changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [FAQ entry](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Will_PostgreSQL_handle_recent_daylight_saving_time_changes_in_various_countries.3F), PostgreSQL is coming with the latest tzdata database. In order to keep it up to date, one should install minor PostgreSQL releases on a regular basis.

It is also possible to have PostgreSQL compiled with system tzdata database support using the `--with-system-tzdata` configure option.

In both cases, running server will not monitor for changes in the tzdata databases, so you'll have to explicitly notify it via the restart.

Comment: Note that the 'latest' version of the Olson database changes quite frequently, and probably a lot more frequently than PostgreSQL is released.  The normal rate is 10-20 times per year.  The current version is 2012c, for example, and the last version last year was 2011n.